# check given date is between two dates in List

Tags: java, list, date

I have `LinkedList` of generic `Date`

```
LinkedList<Date> dateList = new LinkedList<Date>();`
        try
        {
        a= sdf.parse("21/03/2000");
        b= sdf.parse("21/03/2006");
        c= sdf.parse("18/09/2008");
        }catch(ParseException pe)
        {
            System.out.println("not a date formate");
        }
        dateList.add(a);
        dateList.add(b);
        dateList.add(c);
```

if a user enters a date i.e 12/05/2002, so the user should get a prompt that the entered date is between `21/03/2000` and `21/03/2006` and also it should give the answer that "the given date is coming after `21/03/2000`".

I tried sorting. but didn't work. new to `Date` class.

Comment: What have you tried, you must come up with your solution that you have been working on and what problem you faced in that?

Comment: ma'am, i am not getting the idea for that, thats why i post my question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 Date minDate, maxDate;   // assume these are set to something
 Date date;               // the date in question

 return date.after(minDate) && date.before(maxDate);
```

> You can do something like this

```
    Date a = new Date("21/03/2000");
    Date b = new Date("21/03/2006");
    Date c = new Date("18/09/2008");
    
    List<Date> dateList = new ArrayList<Date>();
    
    Date date = new Date("18/09/2005");
    
    dateList.add(a);
    dateList.add(b);
    dateList.add(c);
    
    for (Date minDate : dateList) {
        for (Date maxDate : dateList) {
            //System.out.println("After " + date.after(minDate));
            //System.out.println("Before " + date.before(maxDate));
            System.out.println("Date " + date + " is After " + minDate + " and Before " + maxDate + " : " + String.valueOf(date.after(minDate) && date.before(maxDate)));
        }
    }
```

Comment: how can i do it when so many dates are in list!! i know this solution but all my dates are in list.. so how can i do it??

Comment: @chaitanya i have given you loop logic , which you can optimize as per your needs and requirement

Comment: sir, please not that user is going to enter a date, and we have to check that entered date is lies between which two dates in List...!!

Comment: @chaitanya code updated for your help! .. u better tweak and optimize it as per ur needs

Comment: @chaitanya if it helped u , mark the post as required Answer :), thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using Joda-Time instead of playing with java.util.Date directly. Joda-time is class one API for playing with date in Java. It provides lot of utility methods which you can use directly instead of rewriting the same thing again and again.
If you are using maven, you can simply add its dependency and download it.

Answer (score 0):

A simple date comparison program taken from

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-compare-dates-in-java/

I hope you would be able to build your logic on this.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class App 
{
     public static void main( String[] args ) 
    {
        try{

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Date date1 = sdf.parse("2009-12-31");
            Date date2 = sdf.parse("2010-01-31");

            System.out.println(sdf.format(date1));
            System.out.println(sdf.format(date2));

            if(date1.compareTo(date2)>0){
                System.out.println("Date1 is after Date2");
            }else if(date1.compareTo(date2)<0){
                System.out.println("Date1 is before Date2");
            }else if(date1.compareTo(date2)==0){
                System.out.println("Date1 is equal to Date2");
            }else{
                System.out.println("How to get here?");
            }

        }catch(ParseException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: my all dates are in List.. so for that how can i do it?? i am new to java...

Comment: First of all Sort the list. You may use Collection.Sort()  method, then iterate over the list to compare the input date with each entry. As soon get a date greater than the date in list, you could print your output.

Comment: Welcome and thanks for response. If I am able to help you here; please do not forget to accept and upvote the answer :)  .. It will help me in building my reputation.